# If iframe refresh failed, then X

Tags: javascript, iframe, if-statement, refresh

I'm using the following script to refresh my `<iframe>` every 60 seconds.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("tracker").src += "";
}, 60000);
</script>
```

I would like to show a different page/`<iframe>` if the refresh fails. For example, if I'm not connected to any network, then obviously any page refresh will show the "page not found" error.

Instead, I would like to display a different `<iframe>` (e.g. `tracker2`) or different page/message/image to say "Offline". Of course the `<iframe>` will keep refreshing itself until there's internet connection.

I'm pretty sure that's not possible, however I may be wrong. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<iframe>` you're loading is on a different domain, then no, it's not possible. Otherwise, you can use Ajax to check the status:

```
var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();

rq.open('GET', document.getElementById('tracker').src, true);

rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(rq.readyState === 4) {
        if(rq.status === 200) {
            // All is well
        } else {
            // Show your backup element
        }
    }
};

rq.send(null);
```

Comment: @EliUnger: What's the `<iframe>` for, then? Ajax is usually nicer.

Comment: Minitech is right, u can.only check return value of loading iframe,

Comment: I'm using a Windows 7 gadget/widget to track customer deadlines. There's the widget html file, inside it there's an iframe showing a local PHP page. It helps me to keep track of important dates. However, if I don't have internet access, I see the 'page not found' error. I would like to see 'offline' message instead, or to point to a different iframe (e.g. tracker2). I was wondering, is Ajax = Javascript? In other words, to use the above code, I need to use <Javascript> tags?

Comment: @EliUnger: Ajax is just a way of using JavaScript, so yes, it should be part of your script, inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks. So my SetInterval function will go to // All is well?

Comment: @EliUnger: Nope; the Ajax request goes inside your `setInterval` callback.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't quite get it - mainly because I'm not an expert in Javascript/Ajax. Can you please implement your code in my code? I'd like to see the full script, if possible. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http code of your iframe and depending on that you can render another page

Comment: How do you check the status code of an `<iframe>`? Code is always nice.

Comment: Give me 20 minutes, i am on the train :D

Comment: Can you please post the code once you are back home? I don't quite understand how to use onload to check failure or success of loading iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery ajax to load page content and check page status. For example:

```
<script type=text/javascript>

setInterval(loadIframe, 60000);

function loadIframe()
{

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'document.getElementById('tracker').src',    
    success: function(data){
        alert('horray! 200 status code!');
        document.getElementById("tracker").src += "";
    },
    error: function(data){
        //get the status code
        if (code == 400) {
            alert('400 status code! user error');
        }
        if (code == 500) {
            alert('500 status code! server error');
        }
    },
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where would this piece of ajax code go together with my iframe refresh script?